# File.ReadAllText and Security in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, razor

I Like to read the text of the entire file content ,In my case its a Mail Template which i have to read and then apply the object and send the data back. Do i have to give the file read permission explicitly.If So how can do it

Answer (score 2):

By default the account IIS runs on does not have as many permissions as a user account. As a result, you must either grant the IIS account permissions, or change the user account it uses.

For the first solution, navigate to the file you are looking to read, right click, and go to properties. Go to the settings tab and click modify. Add the IIS user account to the list, and then grant it the permissions you want it to have.

In the second way, go into IIS Management Tool, and click on Application Pools for your server. On IIS7, you will have a minimum of 4. You are probably using the ASP.NET 4.0 AppPool, and as such, should right click, hit Advanced Options, and scroll down and modify the UserIdentity to an account with permissions to access the file.